# Am I still visible to old contacts I have deleted long ago, when they intall whatsapp if they still have my number in their contacts?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I've had my mobile number 15+ years and have used it for work purposes as well as private over this time, even though its my personal number.

Could someone clarify - if anyone from the distant past who still had my number in their contacts then installed WhatsApp - would they now be able to see me in their WhatsApp contacts even though I deleted them as a contacts long before installing the App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have your old number then they are still able to see your old profile.
You are not deleting your profile by simply uninstalling WhatsApp, you need to properly delete your profile by going into `Settings->Account` and select `Delete my account`.
Then your old profile is deleted and nobody will be able to see it or send any messages to it.

Comment: I don't have an old profile and haven't uninstalled WhatsApp - perhaps you misunderstood. WhatsApp wasn't around when I originally entered the old contact numbers in my address book.  But, if I was still in their contacts and they recently installed WhatsApp - would they see me as one of their contacts there, even though they had been deleted from my contacts years ago before I ever installed WhatsApp?  Should I be able to see every person who has me as their contact on WhatsApp anyway?

Comment: You see every contact you have the number of, regardless of them having yours AFAIK.

Comment: But am I showing as a contact in their WhatsApp if they kept my number in their address book?

Comment: Yes you do. If they do not remove your number, they always see you.